# Écriture de "flèche" et "fléchissant"

Tags: diacritiques, écriture

Question bête peut-être mais je ne trouve pas une explication. Pourquoi les écritures des mots *flèche* et *fléchissant* sont différents du point de vue des accents (aigu vs grave) ?

Comment: Je me pose la question inverse: pourquoi penses-tu qu'ils devraient avoir le même accent ? Le son n'est pas le même (/ɛ/ vs /e/), et les deux mots n'ont pas la même étymologie du tout (d'après le wiktionnaire, *flèche* a une lointaine origine germanique, apparentée respectivement au néerlandais *vliegen*, à l'allemand *fliegen* ou à l'anglais *to fly*, tandis que *fléchir* vient du latin *flectere*)

Comment: @Greg Merci. Pourquoi tu ne donne pas ça comme réponse ?

Comment: ... j'avoue que j'étais tellement étonné de la question que je pensais qu'il y avait une autre raison à la question ou que quelque chose m'échappait... J'ai cherché midi à quatorze heures...

Comment: @Greg Je m'excuse de t'avoir fait chercher autant du temps:-)!

Comment: ne pense que pas que j'ai cherché 2 heures :* ) *Chercher midi à quatorze heures* est une expression qui signifie "chercher une explication ou une solution compliquée à un problème très simple".

Comment: @Greg Merci ! Je n'y ai jamais pensé:-)! J'ai appris qqch !

Comment: @Greg même si l'étymologie est en jeu, ça ne s'applique pas à l'adjectif *fléché*, pour lequel c'est l'alternance assez standard notée par Teleporting Goat qui s'applique.

Comment: Exact: *flécher* suit le modèle de conjugaison des verbes en -e*er (ex: sécher, céder, etc). où le è devient é quand la syllabe suivant n'est pas muette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comme Greg l'a signalé en commentaire, ces mots n'ont pas la même étymologie, mais ce phénomène est très fréquent qu'on observe aussi sur des mots qui ont la même origine.

> repère / repérer
>
> flair / flairer
>
> raide / raidissement

Une syllabe finale qui se prononce /ɛ/ est souvent transformé en /e/ quand elle se retrouve en milieu de mot. Ce ne serait pas naturel de prononcer "repèrer", selon moi c'est la prononciation qui s'est naturellement ajustée vers la simplicité, et l'orthographe a suivi. Les accents ont été formalisés assez tard en français et la prononciation de ces mots les précédait probablement.

Comment: En prononciation "standard", le son  /ɛ/ est le même dans *flairer* et *flair* - même si comme évoqué abondamment dans d'autres questions, il y a une forte tendance en France à prononcer de plus en plus /ɛ/ comme /e/.